# Tips for reducing the size of an ID field

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with 30M rows.  Some of the columns include ID fields which are just very large integers.  E.g.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(SomeID = c(8762438732197823423,
                            1236487432893428732,
                            290234987238237842))
```

I suspect that reducing the size of these IDs will speed up joins and other process on my data. What's a good method for doing this?  For example, I could map unique ID's to {1, 2, 3...} or {A, B, C, ...}. Also not sure what datatype (integer or character?) is best for storing these ID fields.

Comment: if you want to do some experimenting, look at the function `object_size()` in the `pryr` package. I suspect that you can't actually do better than integers. The only alternative is strings, and I can't imagine those are smaller or faster. If it turns out that "big" integers are in fact slower for joins than "small" integers (which I doubt), you could store them as a factor, so you have integers 1:3e7 "underneath" your ID column, and the big long ID numbers are just labels. But again my hunch is that it won't make a difference

Comment: If you suspect something regarding performance, your first step should be benchmarking.

Comment: Theoretically the join speed could increase by reducing the size of the IDs since more data fits in memory, thus reducing IO requirements. Also the data loads quicker, even further reducing IO requirements.

Comment: Uhmm, those are not regular integers.

Comment: Check out 10000000000100000L. Then look at 10000000000100000 - 10000000000100001.  You need to make sure that your IDs are characters to avoid the floating point trap.

Comment: operations in data.table on 30M rows should take < 1s... where are you and what performance do you try to achieve

Comment: Storing an `id` as a character makes the most sense. Factors save no memory relative to characters, and some sort of "character cache" in R stores each unique string only once and makes every variable using that string into a pointer to the cache. If you want `id`s that are easier to read, use `DT[,id2:=as.character(.GRP),by=id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of an integer in R is `2^31 - 1` which is 2147483647. Integers larger than that can be stored in doubles, but as @Roland points out above, there is a limit of precision for the significand of 53 bits, so the maximum integer that can be stored accurately is `2^53`. Try `2^53 - (2^53 - 1)` and you'll get 1. Try `(2^53 + 1) - 2^53` and you'll get 0.

For your original question, there's not much in it if you're talking about using data.table joins:

```
library("data.table")
library("microbenchmark")
f <- d <- a <- data.table(x = runif(100, 0, 2^53 - 1), y = rnorm(100))
g <- e <- b <- data.table(x = sample(a$x, 40), z = rnorm(40))
d$x <- sample(1:100)
e$x <- d$x[match(b$x, a$x)]
f$x <- as.character(f$x)
g$x <- as.character(g$x)
setkey(a, x)
setkey(b, x)
setkey(d, x)
setkey(e, x)
setkey(f, x)
setkey(g, x)
microbenchmark(a[b], d[e], f[g], times = 1000L)

##Unit: microseconds
## expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
## a[b] 569.079 623.0495 696.8870 649.4150 699.8465 4160.852  1000
## d[e] 570.141 621.2795 719.7463 647.6455 708.5170 5305.024  1000
## f[g] 549.968 598.4520 665.4203 622.8720 674.1880 3667.156  1000
```

If you wanted to do it though, you could create a new data.frame or data.table with columns containing old and new ids, and then use the `match` function as seen in the code above to change the ids over.